# Exporting ERA5 hourly data from Earth Engine not working

Tags: google-earth-engine

My overall objective is to extract all areas that have a night time temperature <= 0 degrees C from the ERA5 hourly collection on Earth Engine, consideirng the time period 1981-2020 over a entire country (not points, polygons). The steps I have followed are -

1. Filter entire collection to have images only from 10pm-6am (night time defined in my project) (lines 141)
2. Convert images to degrees celcius (lines 146-149)
3. Reclassify all pixels such as pixels with night time temp <=0 is 1 and rest is 0 over the entire collection (lines 151-155)
4. Reduce the collection by sum to get the number of times a pixel has night time temp <=0 in a day (lines 159-175)
   5)Again reclassify like step 3 such that if temperature dropped <=0 in a day, pixel value is 1, else 0 (lines 180-183)
5. Again reduce by sum like step 4, such that pixel value is number of days in which nigh time temp dropped <=0 in a month (lines 185-201)
6. Finally reduce by sum again, pixel value is number of days temp dropped <=0 in a year (lines 205-221)
7. Reclassify again such that all pixels with value > 15 is 1 and rest is 0. This means that all pixels that had more than 15 days of night time temp dropping to <=0 in a year is 1 and rest is 0.
8. Last reduction by sum where pixel value means number of years in which there was >15 days of nght time temp dropping <=0
   10 ) Export to drive.

I have completed above for India as an example and I have initiated the script only for 2 years- Jan 1981 to dec 1982.

Everything runs. However the export stops after 2.5-3.5 hours with the error

Error: reduce.sum: Error in map(ID=0): Image.gt: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1. (Error code: 3)

How do I figure out which images (hours) do not have any bands and exclude these images at any step? Alternatively how do I correct this script so it runs and exports out a binary raster, for a country, indicating areas where min 15 days of a year had night time temp dropping below freezing?

[Here is the code editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftrishagopalakrishna%2Fdefault%3AClimate%2FNighttime_Temp2) starting lines 122

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me when one of my filters is not working properly. For example, an ImageCollection filter might not be returning any images.

In this case, I think the cause is that mapping a function over an ImageCollection (e.g., (`image.subtract(273.15)` in line 148) doesn't conserve the image properties, including the `system:time_start` and `system:time_end` properties that GEE uses to filter by date. The later operations that apply a `.filterDate()` filter then fail to find any images, hence the error.

The workaround I use is to manually set a new `system:time_start` and `system:time_end` property for each image when you map a function over an ImageCollection, e.g., in line 152:

```
var filtered_tempToDegrees = filtered_data.select('temperature_2m').map(function(image){
  return image.subtract(273.15);
});
```

becomes

```
var filtered_tempToDegrees = filtered_data.select('temperature_2m').map(function(image){
  return image.subtract(273.15)
              .set("system:time_start", image.get("system:time_start"),
                   "system:time_end", image.get("system:time_end"));
```

And so on for each operation.

It is a bit cumbersome to apply this to each step, but it should preserve the date-time property and allow the filters to work. I'd love to know if there is a better way!

Answer (score -1):

You can explicitly filter for images with certain band names:

```
var result = collection.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'temperature_2m'))
```

Comment: Yes I have done this already in my script and this is not the problem. The image export runs for 5 hours and gives the error that I have provided, without any indication of errors in the script or generally any errors.

Comment: Also, calendarRange is an expensive filter; you should use the metadata property 'hour' instead, because there will already be an index for it.
`var filtered_data= hour.filter('hour >= 22 || hour <= 5')`

Comment: Ah, I think I (finally) see the bigger issue:  you're running filterDate on images that no longer have a start time in them, so you're always getting 0 images from all of those steps.  When you do math or boolean comparisons on an image, you need to use `.copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])` at the end of each function, to reassign a time_start to the image.